# Name not defined error Python

Tags: python, function

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/CurrencyCoverter/currencyconverter.py", line 16, in <module>
    if userChoice == "1":
NameError: name 'userChoice' is not defined
```

If I try to run my currency converter script, here is the script (not currently finished):

```
def currencyConvert():

    userChoice = input("What do you want to convert? \n1.)USD > UK \n2.)USD > UK \n")


if userChoice == "1":    
    userUSD = imput("ENTERAMOUNT")

    UK = userUSD * 0.62
    print ("USD", userUSD, "= ", UK, "UK")



elif userChoice == "2":
    print ("Choice = 2")

else:
     print ("Error, Please Choose Either Option 1 or 2")
```

Comment: Please, correct the indentation.

Comment: You can't access local function variables like this. You need to either have your function return something (this is better solution in your case) or make userChoice global. There may be also problem with userUSD = imput("ENTERAMOUNT") (did you mean input()? If you did and you're using Python 3, next line may also give you undesired result, because you'd be multiplying string and integer, so your line should look like this: userUSD = float(input("ENTER AMOUNT")))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I hope the indentation is just messed up here and not in your actual script; otherwise, that should be your first priority.

I think you're misunderstanding the point of a function. You're defining this function to get input, and then discard it (because it is not returned). Furthermore, you never call the function.

If I were you, because the function is essentially one line of code, I would remove the function altogether.

In addition, the content of your `else` block leads me to believe that the overall form of your script is broken. I would do something like the following:

```
# I kept the function in this example because it is used twice. In your example, it was only used once, which is why I recommended removing it.
def getChoice():
    return input("What do you want to convert? \n1.)USD > UK \n2.)USD > UK \n")
userChoice = getChoice()
while userChoice != "1" and userChoice != "2": # better yet, you could have a list of valid responses or even use a dictionary of response : callback
    userChoice = getChoice()
# Process input here
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access `userChoice`, which is only available in the scope of `currencyConvert`, outside the function.

To fix the problem, make `currencyConvert` return `userChoice` and then access it like this:

```
userChoice = currencyConvert()
```

In other words, your code should look like this:

```
def currencyConvert():

    userChoice = input("What do you want to convert? \n1.)USD > UK \n2.)USD > UK \n")

    # Return userChoice
    return userChoice

# Access userChoice (the return value of currencyConvert)
userChoice = currencyConvert()

if userChoice == "1":    
    userUSD = imput("ENTERAMOUNT")

    UK = userUSD * 0.62
    print ("USD", userUSD, "= ", UK, "UK")

elif userChoice == "2":
    print ("Choice = 2")

else:
    print ("Error, Please Choose Either Option 1 or 2")
```